# Deform the boundary of the Möbius band in the proper way

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, visualization, mobius-band

The boundary of a Möbius band is an unknot in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so we can deform it via an ambient isotopy to the standard circle in a plane. In this way, how does the Möbius band look like (i.e. how the standard circle bounds a Möbius band in $\mathbb{R}^3$)? I can hardly imagine it. Could someone visualize it?

Comment: Yes, it can be visualized; I've done so. Unfortunately, my drawing skills are far lower than would be required to show you what I saw. And a verbal description also seems hopeless. So I hope someone with far better drawing skills comes along to give an answer to this question. (As a step toward the visualization, try to imagine what happens to the "middle circle" of the Möbius band while you deform the boundary.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip#Making_the_boundary_circular

Comment: @tomasz: That's not the point of the question.  The author understands very well that the border of a Möbius strip **is** a circle. The question is about deforming the strip in such a way that the border matches that of a **flat circle**.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: Ah. I see, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Werner Boy's Surface (with a Hole)

A really nice way to represent it is [Boy's Surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy%27s_surface) with a hole poked in it.

Boy's surface is an [immersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)) of the 2-dimensional projective plane $P$ into Euclidean $\Bbb R^3$.  It's not an embedding because it has self-intersections and a triple point.  But it's smooth everywhere and has no pinches or creases or cusps.

Now $P=M+D$ where $M$ is a Möbius band and $D$ is a disk, i.e. gluing $D$ and $M$ together gives $P$.  The other way round, poking a hole (removing $D$) from $P$ will yield $M$.  Notice that we can pick to remove a disc that does not intersect with the remaining $M$.

The page above has images of a sculpture in Oberwolfach, which is specially nice because it is minimizing [Willmore energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willmore_energy) using Bryant-Kusner-parametrization.  Removing the top dome would leave a Möbius band with a flat circle as its boundary.

[image: Boy's Surface in Oberfolfach]

And there are also nice animations, cf. [youtube: Boy's surface](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=boy%27s+surface).

Great David Hilbert conjectured that no such immersion exists, but Werner Boy proved him wrong.

---

### Möbius Snail

A different representation with circular boundary is the *"Sudanese Möbius strip"* which has no self-intersections.  An image and description are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip#Making_the_boundary_circular).
[image: Sudanese Möbius Strip]

Adding a disc in order to complete it to the projective plane will introduce self-intersections and creases, though, i.e. places where the surface is not smooth.  More renderings are [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MobiusSnail2B.png).

[image: Möbius Snail]

---

### Möbius Wheel (from Boy's Surface)

Returning to Boy's surface, here are some renderings of a Möbius strip with (almost) circular boundary: [W1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Immersed-Moebius-1.png),
[W2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Immersed-Moebius-2.png),
[W3](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Immersed-Moebius-3.png),
[W4](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Immersed-Moebius-4.png).  These renderings were created by changing the Bryant-Kusner parametrization in such a way that only a part is rendered (which effectively pokes a hole) and by pulling the boundary of the resulting Möbius strip to the equatorial plane.  The resulting shape has $D_{2\cdot 3}$ dihedral symmetry with a triple-point in the center. There is a  [detailed description](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Immersed-Moebius-1.png).

[image: Möbius Wheel]
[image: Möbius Wheel]
[image: Möbius Wheel]
[image: Möbius Wheel]

---

All images from Wikipedia / Wikimedia Commons.

Comment: Thank you, I think you answered my quesion. I am a little confused with the construction from Boy's surface. I know after removing a disk we get a Möbius band, but how to guarantee that it is embeded? How to guarantee that the boundary of such a disk looks like a standard circle?

Comment: @Wenbo Liao: It's not exactly a circle in the sense of $x^2+y^2=1$, only in the limit where the removed disc tends to arbitrarily small.  However, the boundary is smooth and circle-ish, and the Möbius band in located in the "inner" of the circle &mdash; in contrast to the Möbius snail which runs into the bounding circle from inside, from outside, from below, from above etc.

Comment: The snail looks very similar to what I "saw"; thank you for the pictures.